# SQL queries are harming the speed of my website - 11 seconds load

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I am using data web services to transport the data from DB to website. I am accessing 4 tables for example (each entity) in separate queries to services.

Example:

- Table1
- Table2
- Table3
- Table4

Pseudo-code that I use:
Foreach Table 1
- Get Table 2
- Get Table 3
- Get Table 4

I get 1000 queries in this case. What the hell?

How do I run this in 1 query?

I have few solutions in my head, but I am not sure:

- First solution - 1 View, which basically creates custom "entity" for
  my web data services.
- Second solution is to ditch web services, and
  use direct proxy to DB.
- Third solution to resolve this would be
  Microsoft Cache?

But I would have to do this for each "huge" operation like this, which really de-motivates me.

Example of method which creates 1000 queries and loads the page in 11 seconds. I know this is totally unacceptable way and poor written method, but what would you suggest:

```
public List<OfferLocalizedContent> GetOffersWithContent(long customerId)
{
    var countryCode =
        this._httpContext.Request.Cookies["countryCode"];

    var offers =
        this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
            .OfferClientRepository
            .GetAllOffers(countryCode.Value, customerId);

    List<OfferLocalizedContent> list = new List<OfferLocalizedContent>();

    foreach (var offer in offers)
    {
        var localizedContent =
            new SyndicateBaseModel(this.ClientRepositoryBuilder)
                .GetLocalizedContent(null, offer, null);

        OfferLocalizedContent model = new OfferLocalizedContent();
        model.Offer = offer;
        model.LocalizedContentModel = localizedContent;

        var lotteries =
            this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                .LotteryClientRepository
                .GetLotteriesByOfferId(offer.Id);

        var currencyRate =
            this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                .CurrencyRateClientRepository
                .GetCurrencyRateBasedOnCountryOrCustomer(countryCode.Value, customerId);

        model.Jackpot =
            new LandingPageBaseModel(this.ClientRepositoryBuilder)
                .GetFeedJackpot(lotteries, currencyRate.Type, offer) / 1000000;

        list.Add(model);
    }

    return list;
}
```

GetFeedJackpot loops through lotteries again and calculates some info, which makes it loop inside of loop.

```
public decimal GetFeedJackpot(List<Lottery> lotteries, byte customerAccountType, Offer offer = null)
        {
            decimal tempPrice = 0;
            decimal realPrice = 0;

            var currencyRates =
                this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                    .CurrencyRateClientRepository
                    .GetCurrencyRates();

            foreach (var item in lotteries)
            {
                var feedMapping =
                    this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                        .FeedScraperLotteryMappingClientRepository
                        .GetFeedScraperLotteryMappingByLotteryId(item.Id);

                if (feedMapping != null)
                {
                    List<DrawDay> drawsList =
                        this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                            .DrawDateClientRepository
                            .GetDrawDaysByLotteryId(item.Id);

                    var jackpot =
                        feedMapping
                            .FeedScraperJackpots
                            .OrderByDescending(fsj => fsj.CreatedOn)
                            .Take(11);

                    if (jackpot.FirstOrDefault().Amount == 0)
                    {
                        var jackpotAverages = jackpot.Skip(1);

                        if (jackpotAverages.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_jackpot in jackpotAverages)
                            {
                                tempPrice += item_jackpot.Amount / jackpotAverages.Count();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempPrice = jackpot.FirstOrDefault().Amount;
                    }

                    if (lotteries.Count == 1 || offer.CurrencyType != 5)
                    {
                        realPrice += tempPrice;
                    }
                    else if(lotteries.Count > 1 && offer.CurrencyType == 5)
                    {
                        realPrice +=
                            new WinningBaseModel(this.ClientRepositoryBuilder)
                                .ConvertLotteryAmountToAccountCurrency(currencyRates, tempPrice, lottery.CurrencyType, customerAccountType);
                    }
                }
            }

            return
                Math.Round(realPrice / 1000000m) * 1000000;
        }
```

Basically example of Sql Profiler in operation(1000 queries what?):
[image]

I host my stuff on Azure server:
DB - Data Web Service - Website

When I monitored Web Service website, It was fully overloaded, therefore lag when loading the website.

Comment: Sounds like you are lazy loading when you want to eager load. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading/

Comment: yes lazy loading is the problem.. i guess i will have to use eager and disable lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few ways to reduce the loading time.

1. Implement a paging system to reduce the number of offers shown on the page.
   If your customer had 1 million offers would they really want to see all 1 million on a single page?

e.g.

```
public List<OfferLocalizedContent> GetOffersWithContent(
       long customerId, int page, int pagesize)
{
   ...
   var offers = this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                    .OfferCLientRepository
                    .GetAllOffers(countryCode.Value, customerId)
                    .Skip(pagesize * page)
                    .Take(pagesize); // or you can do this in GetAllOffers
}
```

2. Use tasks to process each offer.

   foreach(var offer in offers)
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew( ... );
   }